# how to make friendly url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have been trying to force remove some unnecessary part of my url for example remove index.php? from this url.

```
/index.php?task=boost,boosting&action=index
```

The following rules apply not helped

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

how should look like the correct rule to hide unnecessary parts such as index.php or task or action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With below rule you can use url `yourdomain.com/boost/index` you have to still pass value to task & action in some form so you cannot hide all the string from url until it is a post request.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ index.php?task=$1&action=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Description** You may use the following

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```